# how does BodyParser.Raw in Play! framework work?

Tags: playframework, akka-stream, akka-http

I have a question about the `BodyParser.Raw` in Play! framework. [The official document](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/JavaBodyParsers) says:

> Parses the body as a `RawBuffer`. This will attempt to store the body
> in memory, up to Play’s configured memory buffer size, but fallback to
> writing it out to a File if that’s exceeded.

I am having a hard time understanding the above description. Does this mean the following -

If I put the following configurations to my `application.conf` file:

```
play.http.parser.maxMemoryBuffer=128k
play.http.parser.maxDiskBuffer=1G
```

and say my request body has a size of 15MB, then Play! will read/parse the first 128k from the request body, write it to a file, and then stream/parse the next 128k from the request body, write it to the same file, ..., until the 15MB request body is fully parsed? This means that we are using only 128k memory, and we are able to handle a request body whose size is 15MB??

I know it sounds too good to be true...

Could someone kindly explain this?

**UPDATE**:

I want to add some updates here if someone has encountered the same problem here. So @Ivan Kurchenko is right (see below his answer): `BodyParser.Raw` can be used to `POST` a request body that is larger than the configured `play.http.parser.maxMemoryBuffer`. Play! will buffer the request using the disk in that case. In other words, you can `POST` a big request body that is even larger then the available memory in your JVM.

The reason my test failed using Chrome (and also Firefox) was because I had CSRF filter enabled by default. Once I disabled it, everything works fine. For example, the following configurations,

```
play.http.parser.maxMemoryBuffer=1k
play.http.parser.maxDiskBuffer=4G
play.filters.disabled+=play.filters.csrf.CSRFFilter
```

says if the request body is larger than 1k, Play! will use your disk to buffer your request (and certainly, I disable the CSRF filter). Now, with this configuration, I can successfully upload a movie which has a size of more than 3G. So indeed, `BodyParser.Raw` can be used if you need to handle a large request. HTH!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really - if request size exceeds memory threshold, in your case configured as `play.http.parser.maxMemoryBuffer=128k` whole requests body will be written to a temporary file or written to a memory otherwise. And then for the next parsing body will be also streamed either from file or from memory.
Let's look together:

[BodyParser.raw](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/6d0789468909d5d7bdabc6c4207337bd7a7ca9b1/core/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/BodyParsers.scala#L602) - creates `RawBuffer` inside, like for instance here https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/6d0789468909d5d7bdabc6c4207337bd7a7ca9b1/core/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/BodyParsers.scala#L612

And inside `RawBuffer` two methods we interested in :
[push method implementation](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/6d0789468909d5d7bdabc6c4207337bd7a7ca9b1/core/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/BodyParsers.scala#L233) - which accepts incoming bytes and total size exceed buffer size execute `backToTemporaryFile` - meaning write all request to a temporary file.

```
  @volatile private var inMemory: ByteString                 = initialData
  @volatile private var backedByTemporaryFile: TemporaryFile = _
  @volatile private var outStream: OutputStream              = _

  private[play] def push(chunk: ByteString): Unit = {
    if (inMemory != null) { //checks whether current in memory buffer exists

      //if next readed chunk of request body exceeds in memory buffer size
      if (chunk.length + inMemory.size > memoryThreshold) {
        backToTemporaryFile()  // create temporary file
        outStream.write(chunk.toArray)// write buffer to temporary file
      } else {
        inMemory = inMemory ++ chunk // append in memory buffer with next chunk
      }
    } else {
      outStream.write(chunk.toArray) // append in memory buffer with next chunk
    }
  }
```

And then [asBytes method implementation](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/6d0789468909d5d7bdabc6c4207337bd7a7ca9b1/core/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/BodyParsers.scala#L273) - which on its own side read bytes if in memory buffer exists. Or [asFile implementation](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/6d0789468909d5d7bdabc6c4207337bd7a7ca9b1/core/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/BodyParsers.scala#L284) which reads bytes from temporary file.

Also Note: If incoming request body size exceeds configured value in `play.http.parser.maxDiskBuffer` Play will respond with 413 - REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE status.

Comment: Hi @Ivan, thank you for explaining! Reading methods you pointed out does help. Still a few more things: first, the configured memory threshold in my case is `play...maxMemoryBuffer=128k`, `play...maxDiskBuffer=1G` is the **hard drive** buffer size... so I guess it was a typo in your reply?  Secondly - I wrote a tiny app to test this, to simulate a large request body, I was uploading a large file. Now, if `play....maxMemoryBuffer' is configured to be < file size, Chrome gives back "This site can’t be reached" right away, seems like the logic you described in your answer was never triggered??

Comment: @lee Thank you very much for attention to details, yes you are right this was a typo and also I've added code snippet with some comments.

Comment: @lee I'm not sure about Chrome - for testing purpose of such low-level things I prefer using proper tools like Postman or curl which can provide more HTTP low level details.

Comment: Thank you for adding comments to help reading. Will try using other tools to test more. So for the built-in `BodyParser`s that Play! offers, is `BodyParser.Raw` the only one who has this behavior - i.e., check the request size and then decides if an in-memory buffer or a on-disk buffer should be used? by reading the documents, seems like all other built-in BodyParsers will load the request body to memory first...

Comment: @lee I've updated answer about size limitations.

Comment: @lee I'm not sure regarding rest Play! parser - need to take a look individually. But some of the in memory only - like Json or String.